# 'NoneType' object is not iterable python3

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.7, import-from-csv

Hi I have been working on some python script and my problem is when I start that script on server. Thing is I have made module called CSVmanipulation where I have two functions one for reading from .csv and another one is for writing to .csv file. My main script looks like this

```
import time
import scrape
import re
from urlload import load_urls
from setmanipulation import addToSet
from CSVmanipulation import Reader, Writer

USERSURLS = Reader("users.csv")

for newurl in USERSURLS:
    "do something"
```

and my CSVmanipulation script is:

```
import csv

def Reader(nameOfAFile):
        list = []
        if(os.path.isfile(nameOfAFile) == True):
                with open(nameOfAFile) as fajl:
                        reader = csv.reader(fajl)
                        list = [r for r in reader]
                        fajl.close()
                return list
        else:
                print("file doesnt exist")
```

Locally on my machine it works completely fine it reads from .csv file, everything that is read is stored in my list but when I tried this on server i get this output:

```
file doesnt exist
'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

File exists locally and on server and it has content in it.
I've scratched my head like million times and visited every site but I don't know what the heck is wrong. any help I would appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

So essentially your Reader method can't find the file and is returning NONE. Since USERURLS is now NONE you can't use a for loop on it.

Before `USERURLS = Reader("users.csv")`

Try `print(os.getcwd())`

That'll print the programs current working directory and see if that's where your "users.csv" file is.

Comment: it gave me the same path where ""users.csv" is, but when I reuploaded everything it started working except one thing that "file doesnt exist" still pops up. I think that every time I use my var USERSURLS it starts my Reader method. I wanted that my line USERURLS = Reader("users.csv") only goes once and then store whatever it returns to this var

Comment: I've reread this a few times and I don't get it. If it says "file doesn't exist" then that means `os.path.isfile(nameOfAFile)` is returning false thus making the function return `None`. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Little bit rework on my code:
main.py:

```
import time
import scrape
import re
from urlload import load_urls, display
from setmanipulation import addToSet
from CSVmanipulation import Reader, Writer

USERSURLS = []
Reader("users.csv", USERSURLS)

for newurl in USERSURLS:
   "do something"
```

and my CSVmanipulation looks like this:

```
import os
import csv

def Reader(nameOfAFile, list):
        statment = os.path.exists(nameOfAFile)
        print(os.getcwd())
        if(statment == True):
                with open(nameOfAFile) as fajl:
                        reader = csv.reader(fajl)
                        list.extend(r for r in reader)
                        fajl.close()
        else:
                print("file doesnt exist")

        return
```

I just made USERSURL at the begging to be empty list `USERSURL = []`, and because list is a mutable object I just send it in method so every change will take effect.

Btw thanks for the help